# Evaluate the normal convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

I am studying function series and I have this question stopped me.

For all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $, evaluate the normal convergence of the series $$\sum_{n \geq 2} f_n(x) = \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{x e^{-nx}}{\ln(n)}$$ over $[m, \infty)$ s.t $m > 0$, to see if the function $f$ is continuous over $(0, \infty)$.

I thought about studying the behavior of the series of $n$ to see if converge and then to evaluate the convergence with $x$.

This is what I did so far and I don't know what to do more.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{x e^{-nx}}{\ln(n)} = x \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{e^{nx} \ln(n)} \leq x \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{e^{n} \ln(n)}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Which  norm  do you use?

Comment: $xe^{-nx}$ reaches its maximum at $x=\frac 1n$ (provided $\frac 1n> m$) and at $x=m$ when $\frac 1n\leq m$. So for sufficiently large $n$, the sup norm is $\frac{me^{-mn}}{\ln n}$ which is summable.

Comment: @Bernard it is the supremum or uniform

Comment: @GabrielRomon Don't we need to show that $\sum_{n \geq 2} \sup |f_n(x)| < \infty$?

Comment: $\sum_{n\geq 1/m}\frac{me^{-mn}}{\ln n}$ is obviously convergent, hence so is $\sum_{n \geq 2} \sup |f_n(x)|$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Thanks for your comment. Two more questions if you could kindly help me. Why it is **obviously** convergent and then how do we conclude that the function $f$ is continuous over $(0, \infty)$?