# Help to understand an answer for the examination of normal convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

First, thanks for your understanding that we are not all good in mathematics but at least we are working hard to understand it.

I asked this question before but I didn't understand the received comments to help.

My question was: For all $ x\in \mathbb{R} $, evaluate the normal convergence of the series $$\sum_{n \geq 2} f_n(x) = \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{x e^{-nx}}{\ln(n)}$$ over $[m, \infty)$ s.t $m > 0$, to see if the function $f$ is continuous over $(0, \infty)$.

My attempt to solve it

I thought about studying the behavior of the series of $n$ to see if converge and then to evaluate the convergence with $x$ so

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{x e^{-nx}}{\ln(n)} = x \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{e^{nx} \ln(n)} \leq x \sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{e^{n} \ln(n)}
\end{eqnarray}

then I didn't know what to do more.

The comments to help suggested :

$x e^{-nx}$ reaches its maximum at $x=1/n$ (provided $1/n>m$) and at $x=m$ when $1/n \leq m$. So for sufficiently large $n$, the sup norm is $\frac{me^{−mn}}{\ln n}$ which is summable. Then $\sum_{n \geq 1/m} \frac{me^{−mn}}{\ln n}$is convergent, hence $\sum_{n \geq 2} \sup |f_n(x)|$ is also convergent.

What I don't understand is:  $1-$  I don't understand how the sup was found "although it is written but I don't understand it". $2-$ why it is summable and convergent,  and $3-$ how does this help us to conclude that the function f is continuous over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: You really should give a link to [the previous thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3538296/evaluate-the-normal-convergence-of-the-series), if nothing else, to give due credit to @GabrielRomon for the assistance they have already given you, even if you didn't entirely understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes for sure I appreciated his help and I tried to tag him in my post but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to find the supremum of a smooth function is to find where the derivative is $0$.

if $f_n(x) = xe^{-nx}/\ln n$, then
$$f_n'(x) = \frac{(1-nx)e^{-nx}}{\ln n}$$
Setting that equal to $0$ and noting that $e^{-nx}/\ln n$ is never $0$, you get $1-nx = 0$ or $x = \frac 1n$. Because $e^{-nx}$ is always positive, the sign of $f_n'(x)$ is determined by the $(1-nx)$ factor. So it is positive if $x < \frac 1n$ and negative when $x > \frac 1n$. I.e., $f_n(x)$ is increasing to the left of $\frac 1n$ and decreasing to the right. So $x = \frac 1n$ is a maximum.

But your functions are restricted to the domain of $[m, \infty)$. If $\frac 1n$ is in that domain, then it is the maximum, and $$\sup |f_n(x)| = f_n\left(\frac 1n\right) = \frac{1}{ne\ln n}$$
If $\frac 1n$ is not in the domain, so $m > \frac 1n$, then remember that $f_n(x)$ is decreasing when $x > \frac 1n$, which is everywhere in $[m,\infty)$. So the maximum value in the domain in this case has to be at $x = m$ and is given by

$$\sup |f_n(x)| = f_n(m) = \frac{me^{-nm}}{\ln n}$$

Now, for all $n > \frac 1m$, we will always have $\frac 1n < m$. So regardless of the $m$ used, for the tail of the series, $\sup |f_n(x)| = f_n(m) = \frac{me^{-nm}}{\ln n}$, and it is only the tail that determines if the series converges or diverges. The front of the series (all terms with $n < N$ for some set $N$) are just a finite sum, which you can always do.

The series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ is normally convergent if $\sum_n \sup_x |f_n(x)|$ converges to a value $< \infty$. As mentioned, we can concern ourselves only with the tail, which is

$$\sum_{n > 1/m,2} \frac{me^{-nm}}{\ln n} = m\sum_{n > 1/m,2} \frac{(e^{-m})^n}{\ln n}\le m\sum_{n > 1/m,2} a^n$$

where $a = e^{-m}$, since $\ln n > 1$ for $n \ge 3$. Now since $m > 0, a= e^{-m} < 1$. Therefore $\sum_n a^n$ converges. And because $\sum_{n > 1/m,2} \frac{me^{-nm}}{\ln n}$ is a positive series that is bounded above by $\sum_n a^n$, it must also converge.

Therefore $\sum f_n(x)$ is normally convergent.

---

As to your question "how does this help to show $f$ is continuous". If you open your textbook to the section about normally convergent functions and study it, you will find the answer to that question. *Don't come here asking questions until you've looked hard at your textbook*. It is your *first* resource for finding answers. At the very minimum, I expect that your textbook includes the result that normally convergent $\implies$ uniformly convergent.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and efforts. Concerning my textbook, you will not believe but unfortunately there is no one or a suggested one. We really have a problem in the basic definitions and we are trying to understand from the solved questions!

Comment: That is a problem. The question is obviously meant to accompany a discussion of the properties of normally convergent functions, including that normally convergent $\implies$ uniformly convergent. And you should be familiar with properties of uniformly convergent sequences and series - if you are not, then I strongly recommend you study them immediately, they are foundational to a large part of real and functional analysis, (including, of course that a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions converges to a continuous function). Wikipedia can help.

Comment: Hi again, I think this part $$\sup |f_n(x)| = f_n\left(\frac 1n\right) = \frac{n}{e\ln n}$$ should be modified to $$\sup |f_n(x)| = f_n\left(\frac 1n\right) = \frac{1}{ne\ln n}$$ right ?

Comment: @jean - Yes, It is now corrected. Thank you.